# Change margin of one class if another class display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to setup an if statement similar to:

If `divID1` element `style="display:block"` then `divCLASS1` add CSS `style="margin-right:0px"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
           if ($('#w2btoTop').element.style('display') == 'block')
    $(".livehelp").css('margin-right','0px');
}
//-->
</script>
```

I dont know to much of what Im doing but would love to see if I'm close to a solving this at all!

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
if ($("#w2btoTop").css("display") === "block") {
    $(".livehelp").css("margin-right", "0px");
}
```

I'd suggest you to read the [official jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to check visibility if elements:

```
$('#w2btoTop').is(":visible") // true if visible
$('#w2btoTop:visible').length // > 0 if visible
```